# try to distinguish button because two button have one class name

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, instagram

i am making a simple project with selenium about making followers generator.But, i get stuck in a case that two button have same class name,i want to automatically press that button but every times i try it's take me to press first button that redirect me to login with facebook(second button is 'sign up' button that exactly i want to press)

see instagram and inspect sign up button and 'login with facebook' button you will notice that both button is using css name
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPSOp.png

Comment: This is happening due to classes assigned to the buttons. Assign ids to the button and you will get rid of that issue. If you want to assign classes only then give different names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to reach the element so try Xpath to reach 'Sign up' button:-

```
.//button[contains(text(),'Sign up')]
```

Comment: that's help me bro, thank you for understanding my broken english!!!